# Italicize inside quotes?

Tags: style

Usually, the name of a newspaper is in italics.
Let's say somebody is speaking in a book.
"I read The Wall Street Journal," Jerry said.
Or is it:
"I read *The Wall Street Journal,*" Jerry said.
Thanks.

Comment: Did you make two accounts just to ask the same question twice? https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/28736/do-you-italicize-fictitious-television-show-in-fiction-book

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do you italicize fictional company names?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/21429/do-you-italicize-fictional-company-names)

Comment: This is definitely a variation on the company name question but I don't see it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

The rules for italicizing the titles of works (such as newspapers, books, albums, journals) are the same inside quotation marks and outside.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it would come down to the editor, more than the writer. But I know that academically that using italics in the way you have done is standard and expected. Not so sure in fiction, if non-fiction I would however use it.