# Italics use in a fiction book

Tags: style

Is a fictitious newspaper, for example, ABCD Times, italicized in a fiction book?
Obviously, The New York Times, a real newspaper, would be italicized in a fiction book, but the question is about whether a fictitious newspaper in a fiction book would be italicized?

Also, if someone were to speak. "I read The New York Times," Mel said. Would the newspaper be italicized if it is in dialogue/in quotes?

No, this question has not been answered before. The following link has to do with company/brand names, so please don't reference me to it. [Do you italicize fictional company names?](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/21429/do-you-italicize-fictional-company-names)

Yes, I posted these questions before, but I've been having trouble with creating an account/using an old account, so I started from scratch all over again and created a new account. Time is of the essence!

Comment: If you read fully though, the Answer provides what should and shouldn't be italicized which includes shows, tv, books, magazines, and so on :) :)

Comment: No, it doesn't, or it's not very clear. My first question relates to fictitious books/magazines/etc., not company/brand names. I'm already aware that you italicize those things you listed. My second question relates specifically to a book/magazine/etc. in dialogue/quotes. You didn't address these topics. :) :) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not using italics and you're including a publication name inside dialogue, you would need to enclose it within single quotes.

I find that to be cumbersome. Using italics instead is an easy way to avoid extra punctuation marks.

My vote is to always italicize real and fake publications within books.